# How to Create WPForms Custom Smart Tag with ACF Link Field in Array

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, advanced-custom-fields, wpforms

I’m currently trying to set up a custom smart tag on WP Forms using a ACF Link Type Field setup with Array.

This process works fine for text based fields, but I’m having problems returning any value because it’s a link field and therefore need to capture URL value.

For extra context, the WP Form is inside a single product page, and it should capture the value, but I can’t seem to get it to work. The field I'm trying to default fill with a smart tag just remains blank.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Snippet…

```
if ("home_report_url" === $tag) {
        $homereportlink = get_field_object("home_report_url", get_the_ID());
        if($homereportlink) {$home_link_url = $homereportlink['url'];}
        $content = str_replace("{home_report_url}", $home_link_url, $content);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for any confusion, but I managed to get it working with some alteration to the if statement and adding an endif

```
if ("home_report_url" === $tag) {
        $homereportlink = get_field("home_report_url", get_the_ID());
        if( $homereportlink ): $home_link_url = $homereportlink['url'];
        $content = str_replace("{home_report_url}", $home_link_url, $content);
        endif;
    }
```